# How to change WordPress Archive Page Title

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to change the text (illustrated on the image below) from 'Portfolio Archives' to 'Shop'.

I have archive.php and portfolio.php files, none of which has any obvious indication of how/where to change the text.

[screen shot http://damtech.it/screen.png](http://damtech.it/screen.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image link is broken...

But the title usually is in your header.php file.

Comment: Should of been FTP'd by now. Thanks for the tip I will check it out.

Comment: Yea I see the image now! If you dont want to change the title for all your files, you can make a custom header-customname.php file and just pull it through your archive page with get_header('customname'); so your archive page can have it's own title :)

Comment: Easy as that it was in the header.php file. Worked a dream. I wont be using the portfolio feature so I shouldnt need it? I will accept your answer in 8 minutes when it lets me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I also come across this problem previous week.I was using a theme.This may help you or may not.But I face same problem ,so I am answering.

If you are using some theme.Then there should be your `Theme Setting`.
Go to `theme setting` and there will be `Header` and `footer` options.You may change this text from there.My problem was solved from there.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who wasted time trying the approved answer, reading the function reference at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header and paying attention to this section:

Multiple Headers

Different header for different pages.

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) :
    get_header( 'home' );
elseif ( is_404() ) :
    get_header( '404' );
else :
    get_header();
endif;
?>
```

The file names for the home and 404 headers should be header-home.php and header-404.php respectively.

leads to the following successful approach.

1. Copy your `(yourthemename)/header.php` file to `(yourthemename)/header-customname.php`
2. Change the `get_header()` call in the file you are targeting to `get_header('customname')`

Job done.

Comment: You would do better to actually include the content of required actions "in the answer" rather than linking externally. You can include the link as an "attribution", but an "answer" should be self contained. Or it's just not an answer.